# Invalid tag: missing manifest digest when exporting nx docker image to GitLab docker container using Azure DevOps CI

Tags: docker, azure-devops, gitlab, devops, cicd

I am trying to export an nx docker image to the GitLab docker container using Azure DevOps CI.
The image is pushed successfully, but it is not tagged properly. I am getting the error **"Invalid tag: missing manifest digest"**.[image]

I have checked the version of the Docker client that I am using, and it is up to date. I have also tried pushing the image again, this time including the manifest digest, but I am still getting the same error.
The image is current, and can be pulled and run normally, however, I'm having the tag issue.

Note that when pushing the image from the local machine, using the same command the image is pushed normally and successfully staged.
I am not sure what else to try. Can anyone help me?

This is a snippet of my azure devops pipeline [image]
And here's the related section in the nextjs project.json setting :
[image]

Any help would be appreciated, thank you !

Comment: This error sounds similar to [this Gitlab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/393202), which has a workaround [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/388865): pass "--provenance=false" to "docker buildx". But with your nx example I am not sure how & where buildx comes into nx...